# Php, code completion for factory methods?

Tags: php

```
class A
{
    public function method1() {}
    public function method2() {}
}

class B
{
    public function method1() {}
    public function method3() {}
}

class Factory
{
    public static function create($className)
    {
        return new $className();
    }
}
```

and now when I try to use it:

```
Factory::create('A')->
Factory::create('B')->
```

Ide wont enumerate any methods, I cant add the appropiate phpdoc.
Of corse I can always wrap it:

```
/**
 * @return A
 */
public static function createA()
{
    return new A();
}
```

but thats not 100% satisfying, especially when I have tons of these.

Comment: I think you need to explain to us what you are trying to achieve

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: done. "10 more to go..."

Comment: I think it totally depends on the editor.
See for example PhpStorm's example: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Comment: A reliable implementation of this isn't possible unless the IDE actually runs the code.

Comment: unfortunately, you've already identified the only solution (to the best of my knowledge) which is to implement the phpdoc in each factory

Answer (score 1):

If factory can return instances of different classes then all this classes should implement a common interface. In this case you should not care about actual class, but work with this interface.

If created objects should have different methods (which cannot be covered by generic interface), then obviously factory should have separate methods for every type of objects (or even separate factories).

If you really need for method with different types of return values, if type-safety is irrelevant and you only want to IDE autocompletion, then just add a [doc-comment with multiple types](http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html#multiple-types-combined) like following (PHPStorm and NetBeans support this notation):

```
/**
 * …
 *
 * @return A|B|C
 */
```